# Empty function C

Tags: c

How could you define a function that does nothing?

If you write:

```
void function(void);
```

it would be taken as a prototype but not as a function. Would that other one be correct?

```
void function(void) {}
```

Comment: Yes. yada yada.

Comment: C have *declarations* and *definitions*. The first line of code you show is a *declaration*. It basically only tells the compiler that somewhere in some [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) there exists a function with the specified name and arguments and return type. The second line of code is an actual *definition*. It tells the compiler that "*this is it*, this is an actual function". And if the function haven't been declared before, it also acts as a declaration.

Comment: Also note that a good compiler would be able to detect empty functions defined in the translation unit it's currently compiling, and will be able to use optimizations to not actually call the function, since the call will not do anything. Such optimizations are not possible across translation units without a good linker.

Comment: "*does nothing*" but, putting anarchistic compiler optimisations aside, is being called and returns.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Why don't you give me more upvotes than downvotes? Don't you consider this question as useful?

Comment: @joelac If you got the answer you need, try not to worry too much about the votes.  SO has some pretty particular ideas about what makes a "good" question, and basic questions don't always make the cut.  The party line is that you're not supposed to take this personally, but of course it's hard not to.

Comment: @Steve Summit Wooa thank you very much Steve. And yeah, got the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this

`void function(void){}`

is possible and it's a correct function definition.

*the function can't have arguments and it can return nothing ?* But it can have it's own  function body though it doesn't expect any argument & return nothing.

For e.g

`void function(void){ printf(" welcome to SO\n"); }`

Answer (score 0):

Would that be correct?

```
void function(void) {}
```

Yes, a function that does not accept any arguments, it does not return anything, and does nothing in its body.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I second one is a function that does nothing.
It merely can act as a set of statements stacked together (complex statement) that you might use in another function which neither requires input not gives you any output.